# How to add specific file to .gitignore in Visual Studio solution?

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore

I want add specific file to be not tracking by `git`. Im using default [Visual Studio .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) that was generated by `Visual Studio` while making solution.

Now, i have a file that i dont want to be tracked. I tried to add this file to `.gitignore`:

```
/TaskManager-wpf/Services/UrlBuilder.cs
```

but when i paste it into last line of `.gitignore` it not work and when i change this file, `Visual Studio TeamExplorer` still tracking this file and want to commit changes on it.

My question is, how to add specific code `.cs` file into `.gitignore`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gitignore` will prevent untracked files from being added (without an add -f) to the set of files tracked by git, however, git will continue to track any files that are already being tracked.

[you can see the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/3739149)